# How to Call function on laravel pivot model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pivot-table

I was trying to get the attendance of each user in a course where the users and the courses have many to many relationship and the attendance table is based on the relationship.
But i couldn't call `$user->pivot->attendance();` directly i had to call for the pivot object it self so i can call a function to it as you can see in the answer

The Following is a sample of my Database scheme

I need to run

```
$users=$course->users;
foreach($users as $user)
{
    $user->pivot->attendance(); //error in this line
}
```

this line gives and error

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attendance()

users

```
id
name
etc
```

courses

```
id
name
startDate
endDate
```

course_user

```
id
course_id
user_id
payment
regDate
status
```

userattendance

```
id
course_user_id
time
inOrOut
```

And here is the CourseUserPivot Class

```
class CourseUserPivot extends Eloquent {


    protected $table ="course_user";



    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Course'); 
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User'); 
    }

    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Userattendance','course_user_id');
    }
}
```

P.S: $user->pivot->payment  works and displays the attribute but i cant call methods

Comment: You have to override the `newPivot` method in order for it to use your own pivot class.

Comment: @JosephSilber Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `$user->pivot->attendance();` as this calls attendance on the user object not on the pivot object

You will have to fetch the pivot object then call the function like so

```
CourseUserPivot::find($user->pivot->id)->attendance();
```

make user that  where you used withPivot() function you include the id in the array

like in

```
class Course{
...
...
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Candidate')
                    ->withPivot('id',
                    'summary',
                    'status',
                    'payment'

                    );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange that I'm first guy who +1 this Q/A. thanks to you but I hope if there is a better way since in my case I'm calling this function from within views

Comment: @MohamedKawsara you can call it in the controller $courses->with('users'); and in the view just call foreach on $courses and then foreach on  $course->users as $user normal eagerloading

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing, and I was having trouble getting it to work like I wanted until I included the 'id' column of my custom pivot model in the withPivot() method.

For some context, my database structure is:

- User table

  - id
- Items Table

  - id
- Sets table (defines a set and the items that can be in an instance of it)

  - id
- Set_User table (Custom Pivot Model, instances of a set created by a user)

  - id, set_id, user_id
- Items_SetUser table (items that belong to a set instance that belong to a user)

  - item_id, setuser_id

I do this in the controller to get all the sets that user has made an instance of, with custom pivot table data:

```
$user_sets = \Auth::user()->sets()->withPivot('id', 'name')->get();
```

And then in blade I can access the items associated with each set instance like this:

```
$set->pivot->set_items()->count()
```

Without including 'id' in the call to withPivot(), the above is not possible. Note that set_items() is a method on the custom pivot model that defines a relationship with the items table.