# Laravel Eloquent: My Pivot table has relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here some information about the table

```
User table
-id
-name

UserProduct table
-id
-user_id
-product_id

Product table
-id
-name

Contribution
-id
-user_product_id
-contribution
```

User Model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}
```

Product Model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

UserProduct Pivot Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class UserProduct extends Pivot

{
    public function contribution()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Contribution');
    }
}
```

I try like `auth()->user()->products()->first()->pivot->contribution()` but it gives some error.

> ***Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::contribution()***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234650/how-to-call-function-on-laravel-pivot-model) problem. We cannot call function on pivot object.

### The solution was :

> *First, add **UserProduct** to **aliases** so we can call it in **blade**.*

**config\app.php :**

```
'aliases' => [
   'UserProduct' => App\UserProduct::class, 
],
```

> *Then, use **find** function then call the **relation** function*

**Blade :**

```
@foreach ($product->users as $user)
    @foreach (UserProduct::find($user->pivot->id)->contribution()->get() as $contribution)
         // viewing contribution attribute
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> *Don't forget to include pivot id*

**Product Model :**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
                ->withPivot(['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

could you maybe use [custom pivot table model](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models).

```php
class UserProduct extends Pivot
{
  public function contribution()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Contribution');
  }
}
```

```php
// User model

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->using('App\UserProduct');
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: how do I call contribution() ?

Comment: similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234650/how-to-call-function-on-laravel-pivot-model